# Dynamic query in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am writing an dynamic Query in sqlserver  2005.

```
DECLARE @SQL3 VarChar(2000)                             
SET @SQL3 =' INSERT into @TableClub4 SELECT  ID from Clubcard   '  
print (@SQL3);
Exec (@SQL3);
```

Whenever it excutes it gives me an error

```
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@TableClub4".
```

But I have defined the `@TableClub4` table parameter.

Let me know the syntax, where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a declared table inside a dynamic sql block. You can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableClub4
(
    ID INT
)
DECLARE @SQL3 VarChar(2000)                             
SET @SQL3 =' INSERT into #TableClub4 SELECT ID from Clubcard'
print  (@SQL3);
Exec (@SQL3);
DROP TABLE #TableClub4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table variable is not known inside the dynamic sql, but you can rewrite it to this:

```
DECLARE @SQL3 VarChar(2000)                             
SET @SQL3 ='SELECT  ID from Clubcard'  
print (@SQL3);

INSERT into @TableClub4
Exec (@SQL3);
```